# mirror iPhone 5 display to TV without AirPlay

Tags: hdmi, iphone

Is there any way I can make anything that is currently shown on the screen of an iPhone 5 to be displayed on a regular TV or projector that has the usual HDMI, composite video, DVI, DSub inputs via a simple cable or adapter and without Airplay/Apple TV?

Comment: xbmc supports airplay...

Comment: @TheX I am looking for a solution thar works everywhere where I find a HDMI, compositn video, DVI or DSub input port.

Comment: Okay... just thought I would throw it out there (hence why I didn't make it an answer)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, this is currently not possible as existing adapters are not compatible with the Lightning connector (even with current converters). See this [link](http://www.theverge.com/2012/9/13/3329062/apple-lightning-hdmi-vga-cable-adapter-coming-months) for more information.

At the Apple event on the 23rd October, two new adapters were announced [VGA to Lightning](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD825ZM/A/lightning-to-vga-adapter?fnode=3a) and [Lightning Digital AV (HDMI)](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD826ZM/A/lightning-digital-av-adapter?fnode=3a). If you read the details on the store page carefully, they both say they support mirroring (in the overview section).

Comment: So once those cables/adapters are out, I will probably be able to connect a TV's HDMI or VGA port with the lightning port of the iPhone 5 and the display will be mirrored?

Comment: If Apple implements the same functionality as it currently has, then the answer is yes but we don't know exactly what those adapters will do. For your reference on which adapters current support mirroring, see http://ipad.about.com/od/iPad_Guide/a/How-To-Connect-Your-Ipad-To-Your-Tv.htm

Answer (score 1):

Apple is now showing Lighting to hdmi and vga and can be found on the link below.

http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_iphone/iphone_accessories/cables_docks

Answer (score -2):

no this is not possible right now

Comment: It is possible. Apple currently has 2 options (1 for VGA, 1 for HDMI, as multiple people mention above.